# Создание опций в opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Подскажите, есть ли в опенкарт такая же возможность как и в вордпресс добавлять опции, не создавая новые колонки в бд?
что-то наподобие функций `add_option(), update_option(), get_option()` и таблицы `wp_options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Opencart такого нет, вам придётся создавать дополнительные колонки. Либо поискать модули для этого.